# Get queryset and it's aggregated value at one db query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, aggregation

In Django rest framework view I am making a complex Product annotated queryset which goes to serialization, but at the same time, I need to get its aggregation data to add it to the Response data.

Example (one query):

```
qs = self.filter_queryset(Product.objects.filter(**query_filters)
                         .annotate(current_price=F('some_value') * some_vart)))
```

Then I need aggregated data(second query):

```
min_max = qs.aggregate(Max('current_price'), Min('current_price'))
```

This produces 2 DB queries total. Is there any way to make it hitting DB once? DB is Postgres.

Thx

Comment: Normally this should hit the database once, unless you use `qs` somewhere else, but querysets are *lazy*: they only evaluate with `.aggregate(..)`, iterating over these, determine the `len(...)`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you explain please "but querysets are lazy: they only evaluate with .aggregate(..), iterating over these, determine the len(...), etc."